# IOS 13 not making UIWindow with level .statusbar present over status bar of iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, uiwindow

I am adding an overlay over the status bar of iphone. But when i switched over to IOS 13.1 on xcode 11.1, I am unable to present it over the status bar using UIWindow class

```
class PassTroughWindow: UIWindow {
    var passTroughTag: Int?

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)

        if let passTroughTag = passTroughTag {
            if passTroughTag == hitView?.tag {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return hitView
    }
}


    class ViewController: UIViewController {
                        var window: PassTroughWindow?
             @IBAction func alertButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
                        print("Height : \(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)")
                        print("Height : \(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.maxY)")
                        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.maxY)
                        let banner = UIView(frame: frame)
                        banner.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5
                        banner.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 128.0/255.0, green: 161.0/255.0, blue: 193.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

                        let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
                        label.textAlignment = .center
                        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
                        label.text = "No internet connection"
                        label.textColor = .black
                        banner.addSubview(label)

                        self.window = PassTroughWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                        self.window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
                        self.window?.windowLevel = .statusBar + 1
                        self.window?.addSubview(banner)
                        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                        self.window?.alpha = 1.0

                    }

        }
```

The same code if executed in Xcode 11.1 on IOS 13.1 then it gives this result in debugger () :-
[image]

Whereas, in xcode 10.2 on IOS 12.2 it gives me this result

[image]

End result in IOS 13.1 , Xcode 11.1 is

[image]

And end result in IOS 12.2, xcode 10.2 is

[image]

How can i present overlay over statubar in IOS 13?

Answer (score 0):

The relative APIs and values should have been deprecated in the documents.

The workaround we currrently have is to override `prefersStatusBarHidden`.

Checkout the post I found [here](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages/issues/335).